# inserting text box input into URL parameter without GET method

Tags: forms, post

In this form I want to get the value of the text box Enter Techs name: in to the URL but my form method is post.So that my url would look like

```
http://localhost/cs_3/index.php?page=chat&tech=
```

Is there any way I could do it.Can't use get method because I don't want the message to be seen in the URL.

```
<form method="post" >
<label>Enter Username:<input type="text" name="sender"/></label>
<?php if($user['Level'] == 3){?>
<label>Enter Clients name:<input type="text" name="tech"/></label>
<?php }else{ ?>
<label>Enter Techs name:<input type="text" name="tech" /></label> 
<?php } ?>
<label>Enter Message:<textarea name="message" rows="8" cols="70"></textarea></label>
<div id="submit"><input type="submit" name="send" value="Send Message"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use action param at your form.
Change it on key press in tech input by javascript (easy with jquery).